# Jquery on click does not work for chrome on MAC but works on all other browsers on all OS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, click

---

This code works for all browser but nor for chrome on MAC. Here is my code.

```
        $(document).on("click", '.product',function() {
//$('select.product').on('mouseup, keyup', function() {
//  $product=this.value;
//$('select.product').on('click, , mousedown, keyup',function() {
var $idp = $(this).attr('id');
var $product=$(this).val();

alert($idp);
 var $newID="optionHolder"+$idp.replace(/[^\d.,]+/,'');
 var $newImageHolderID="imageHolder"+$idp.replace(/[^\d.,]+/,'');
    addCheckbox($newID,$product,$newImageHolderID);  
});

function addCheckbox(id,name,imageid) {
//some LOC
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `.click()` function instead of using `.on('click'...`?

Comment: both works on the second click. But I want this to display on the first click. This only happens on chrome on Mac not even on chrome on windows. Chrome version 34.0.1809.0 Dev

Comment: What about changing click with mousedown? I'm not sure how it would behave on chrome for Mac.

Comment: Phil thanks for your help here. I have tried all, but its not working. As you can see I have commented out mousedown. It works with Keyup but does not work with any other event. :(